# Failure delivering result, {who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Failure delivering result `ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {(has extras)}}` to activity

I tried to copy and paste this code: https://github.com/ataradov/alarm-me
into a new project.
However everytime i try to create a new alarm.

Error prompt up.

`at com.example.testtt.reminder.AlarmMe.onActivityResult(AlarmMe.java:105) which is this:mCurrentAlarm.fromIntent(data);`

Here is my current project: https://www.mediafire.com/?ds7paur1fxnici2
You can download it and see the error itself.